# "Client side error after launching browser" with testcafe

Tags: google-chrome, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to launch browser with a url that could record audio and video.  using test cafe. After launching, I see a an Application error, A client side exception has occurred. Below is my code.

[Browser Console Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4yIz.png)

My arguements to run the test -

yarn run testcafe --hostname  chrome e2e\launchwebSDK.js --live --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --use-fake-device-for-media-stream

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that this problem occurs because Chrome doesn't allow calling the getUserMedia API from insecure origins. I recommend you specify `localhost` as a hostname or enable [https mode](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--ssl-options) to bypass this limitation:

`testcafe --hostname localhost ...`

or

`testcafe --ssl pfx=/path/to/cert.pfx ...`